# Selecting a file to upload causes mobile Safari to crash

Tags: html, safari, upload, mobile-safari

I've been experiencing behaviour on, at least my iPhone 6 Plus, when using the `<input type="file">` to let the user upload an image.

```html
<div class="add__from-camera">
    <button class="add__from-camera__btn">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-camera"></i> Add with Camera
    </button>
    <input class="add__from-camera__input" type="file">
</div>
```

This rest case results in crashes of the tab about 50% of the time, and in my app about 90% of the time.

I was 'lucky' enough to get all of Safari to crash once when the error happened, and this was part of the log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00030000006467ba
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WebKit                          0x000000018a48566c WebKit::WebPageProxy::didChooseFilesForOpenPanelWithDisplayStringAndIcon(WTF::Vector<WTF::String, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow> const&, WTF::String const&, API::Data const*) + 44
1   WebKit                          0x000000018a461648 WebKit::WebOpenPanelResultListenerProxy::chooseFiles(API::Array*, API::String*, API::Data const*) + 100
2   WebKit                          0x000000018a461648 WebKit::WebOpenPanelResultListenerProxy::chooseFiles(API::Array*, API::String*, API::Data const*) + 100
3   WebKit                          0x000000018a413020 -[WKFileUploadPanel _chooseFiles:displayString:iconImage:] + 468
```

It seems to indicate an (overflow?) error in display the little thumbnail preview? Is there a way to prevent Safari from crashing when using file input, or at least don't render the thumbnail preview?

Comment: I've observed the same problem on iPhone6 Plus. All you need to demonstrate it is: <html>
<body>
<input type="file">
</body>
</html>

Comment: Hey did you ever work out a fix for this ?

Comment: @AlexFox Sorry, no. We ended up dropping that particular application (it was only a prototype) so we never investigated further.

Comment: using the lower resolution front camera seems to fix this issue, so I think it has something to do with file size, and safari trying to stop you doing something stupid (overflow protection).

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue. Hopefully apple gets it together soon.  [linky](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6707626?start=75&tstart=0)

Comment: Your CodePen link returns a 404 Error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input class="add__from-camera__input" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```