# HTML file type Input tag causes Safari to crash on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: html, ios

Using a HTML file selector tag  causes the Safari mobile  browser to crash when capturing a file via the camera.

The error is described in numerous threads e.g. this one:
[Selecting a file to upload causes mobile Safari to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955216/selecting-a-file-to-upload-causes-mobile-safari-to-crash)

The error is still an issue on iOS 9.2.1.

Anyone got an update on the issue?
Is there a official bug report logged at Apple?

I find it really strange that such a severe error isn't fixed by Apple as the iPhone 6 plus has been one the market for approx. 1½ years!!